# Using SWIG wrapped functions from Windows .dll

Tags: c++, python, dll, shared-libraries, swig

I'm having a problem using functions from a `.dll` shared library that is exported with SWIG interface.

> Version Info
>
> Python: 2.6.4
>
> Swig: 2.0.4

The big picture is: I have some code developed under Linux using C++ and wrapped using SWIG. I compiled the C++ source into a `.so` object under Linux and use the `.so` library in Python.

Now, I need to migrate all these functions to windows and the equivalent for `.so` in Windows is a `.dll`. So, I planned to compile all the C++ source codes into a `.dll` and access them through Python.

So the normal procedure would be: have the C++ source -> wrap them using SWIG -> compile into `.dll` -> access through Python.

There is a huge `.cxx` source file generated using SWIG which contains all the functions I developed. The task now is to compile this SWIG generated  file into a `.dll` so that I can use all the functions later. However, the .cxx file uses some weird way of wrapping all my functions and I have no clue how to use them.

The functions are wrapped as follows. Ssay I have a C++ class called `sdrts_reverse_burst_ff`, after wrapping, the class becomes a function in the `.cxx` file and is defined like this:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {

PyObject *resultobj = 0;

boost::shared_ptr< sdrts_reverse_burst_ff > *arg1 = (boost::shared_ptr< sdrts_reverse_burst_ff > *) 0 ;

  void *argp1 = 0 ;

  int res1 = 0 ;

  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;

  sdrts_reverse_burst_ff *result = 0 ;



  if(!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args,(char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__",1,1,&obj0)) SWIG_fail;

  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_boost__shared_ptrT_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_t, 0 |  0 );

  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {

    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "boost::shared_ptr< sdrts_reverse_burst_ff > *""'"); 

  }

  arg1 = reinterpret_cast< boost::shared_ptr< sdrts_reverse_burst_ff > * >(argp1);

  result = (sdrts_reverse_burst_ff *)(arg1)->operator ->();

  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff, 0 |  0 );

  return resultobj;

fail:

  return NULL;

}
```

That's not all: near the end of this `.cxx` file there is a huge array which contains all the class functions like this:

```
PyMethodDef SwigMethods[] = {

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self)"},

  { (char *)"delete_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr", _wrap_delete_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"delete_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self)"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self, int samples) -> int"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_enable_reverse_burst", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_enable_reverse_burst, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_enable_reverse_burst(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> int"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_reset", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_reset, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_reset(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> int"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_history", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_history, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_history(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> unsigned int"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_multiple", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_multiple, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_multiple(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> int"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_relative_rate", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_relative_rate, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_relative_rate(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> double"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_start", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_start, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_start(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> bool"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_stop", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_stop, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_stop(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> bool"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_read", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_read, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_read(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self, unsigned int which_input) -> uint64_t"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_written", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_written, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_nitems_written(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self, unsigned int which_output) -> uint64_t"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_detail", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_detail, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_detail(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> gr_block_detail_sptr"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_detail", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_detail, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_detail(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self, gr_block_detail_sptr detail)"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_name", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_name, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_name(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> string"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_input_signature", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_input_signature, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_input_signature(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> gr_io_signature_sptr"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_signature", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_signature, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_output_signature(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> gr_io_signature_sptr"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_unique_id", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_unique_id, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_unique_id(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> long"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_to_basic_block", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_to_basic_block, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_to_basic_block(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self) -> gr_basic_block_sptr"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_check_topology", _wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_check_topology, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_check_topology(sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr self, int ninputs, int noutputs) -> bool"},

  { (char *)"sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_swigregister", sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_swigregister, METH_VARARGS, NULL},

  { (char *)"reverse_burst_ff", _wrap_reverse_burst_ff, METH_VARARGS, (char *)"reverse_burst_ff(int max_samples) -> sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr"},

  { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }

};
```

I followed my old experience with `.dll`s and exported all the functions with a simple `__declspec(dllexport)` head. In Python, I can also call the `_wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__` I exported:

```
import ctypes

_dll_func_list = ctypes.WinDLL("func.dll")

_reverse_burst_ref = _dll_func_list._wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr___deref__
```

Yet, that's the furthest I can approach. When I try to access the sub functions in that class, for example,

```
_class_ref._wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst(0)
```

the damned machine told me:

> '_wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst' cannot be found.

When I try to call the function directly and pass in a parameter like this:

```
_dll_func_list ._wrap_sdrts_reverse_burst_ff_sptr_set_reverse_burst(0)
```

The machine says

> WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000004

Does anyone know how to access exported SWIG wrapped functions using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG also generates a .py file, in addition to the .cxx file. Once you've built a DLL (or shared object) on your platform all you need to do to use that in Python itself is

```
import ModuleName
```

where `ModuleName` is what you told SWIG to call the module, either via `%module` in the .i file for from the command line when you called it.

In the SWIG generated Python there is code to handle the loading of the DLL for you - no need to be using ctypes or anything like that with it. The generated code matches the interface you asked SWIG to wrap as closely as possible in Python and magically hands the calls off to the C++ side for you.

Thus if `sdrts_reverse_burst_ff` is a free function you can do:

```
import ModuleName

ModuleName.sdrts_reverse_burst_ff()
```

You need to make sure you build the DLL with the name SWIG expects it to have - it'll be pretty obvious from the exception that Python raises if that's not the case. You probably also want to link it against your implementation that contains  `sdrts_reverse_burst_ff()` unless that's a header only function.

Comment: I do use the generated python file, and it has an import helper. But it fails when import _my_dll, and it says: ImportError: No module named _my_dll. I added the absolute path to _my_dll to both PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it should be able to find it.

Comment: @user1165959 - you need to make sure it's called *exactly* "_my_dll.dll" then if that's what Python complains about. On Windows systems I've tended to just put it in the current directory at the point that Python gets called. Either way ctypes is not the way to fix it - you need to fix the path+loading issue and it'll all just work again.

Comment: Yes, it's called exactly _my_dll.dll, and I also tried putting it under c:\Python27 and it still couldn't find it. It can only find the dll when using ctypes.WinDLL("_my_dll.dll"). But since you mentioned it's not the way to do it, I have a feel that this dll I made was not compiled to a recognizable format to SWIG. The way I use swig is: swig -module _my_dll -fvirtual -python -modern -c++ -outdir . -o _my_dll.cxx _my_dll.i and then I compiled _my_dll.cxx into a dll along with the src I used to generate _my_dll.i using VC++ 2008 express edition. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: @user1165959 - I think that on Windows you need to rename the .dll to .pyd for python to pick it up via the import. (http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll)

Comment: yes, but not through renaming, it's done through rebuilding. I opened an example build that comes with swig and inserted my source and .i file and build from there. A .pyd file has been built and is able to run now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

So the final short answer appears to be that the C++ build should produce `_my_dll.pyd` (not `_my_dll.dll`) in order to be able to import `my_dll` in Python on Windows. This is in contrast to the Linux build, where one would build `_my_dll.so`

Simply renaming .dll file to .pyd works, but it is better to build it, as pointed out in comments above.